# JQuery change $.getJSON url then clone

Tags: jquery

I have a `<li>` item with JQuery code inside. I want to clone this `<li>` and change `$.getJSON url` inside cloned `<li>`. Is it possible?

Here the code:

```
<ul class="exercise2">2:2 Exercise - 1

            <li class="exset327" id="exset327"><var class="exset">327</var>:Сет - <var class="setnum">1</var>
              <a class="DelSet" href="#">[-]</a>
              <script>
                $(".exset327 a").click(function () {
                  $.get("/workouts/del_set/327/"); // Here I want to change '327' in cloned item to some variable then clone
                  $(this).parent().remove();
                  $(".exercise2 li").each(function(){
                    $(".setnum",this).html($(this).index() + 1);
                  });
                  return false;
                });
              </script>
            </li>

        <a class="AddSet" href="#">Add set</a>   // link which make a clone of above <li>
        <script>
          $(".exercise2 a.AddSet").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("/workouts/add_set/2/", function (json) {
              //alert(json.newsetnum);
              var newsetid = json.newsetid;         // returnet from server
              var newsetnum = json.newsetnum;       // returned from server
            // clone
            var clonedLi = $(".exercise2 li:last").clone(true); // 'true' to clone with event handler
            // change attributes
            $(clonedLi).attr("id", "exset" + newsetid);
            $(clonedLi).attr("class", "exset" + newsetid);
            // change content
            $(clonedLi).find(".exset").html(newsetid);
            $(clonedLi).find(".setnum").html(newsetnum);
            // add
            $(clonedLi).insertAfter(".exercise2 li:last");
            });
          });
        </script>
</ul>
```

If I will not change `URL` when I clik to `[-]`(remove) link on cloned `<li>` it is remove previous.

Comment: Perfect. Could you explain how or give a link? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer you with an alternative route, since your way of doing it doesn't seem optimal. Cloning DOM elements is fine but cloning  tags is not really elegant.

It seems like you're doing the same actions but with different elements or variables. There's a nice way of doing these kinds of work with generic classes - and making them more precise using .data();

The HTML

```
<li class="exset327" id="exset327">
  <var class="exset">327</var>:Сет - <var class="setnum">1</var>
  <a class="DelSet" href="#" data-exset="327" >[-]</a>
</li>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".DelSet", function() {
    var exset = $(this).data("exset");

    $.get("/workouts/del_set/"+exset+"/"); 
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".exercise2 li").each(function(){
      $(".setnum",this).html($(this).index() + 1);
    });
    return false;
 });
```

This part of javascript will make sure that every new ".DelSet" will have a click listener, and execute the code below.

So all you will have to do, is clone the < li > and modify data-exset.

```
$(clonedLi).find(".DelSet").data("exset", netsetid);
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Exactly what I want. Thank you.